# Foolproof installation of Clojure on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, clojure

I'm now programming for more than 30 years and in this time tried a lot of programming languages. I've never seen a programming language as difficult to install as Clojure. Even Jython, which is also build for JVM, installs in seconds and instantly works properly.

For Clojure you have to fiddle around with downloading and installing scripts via shell, starting leiningen in background or trying to install add-ons for your favorite IDE. You stick to folder structure, have to set environment variables manually, ...

Is there any easy and foolproof way to install Clojure with a 'normal' editor or simple IDE on windows? (mostly preferred with an one-file-installer)

Comment: lein repl works, but lein test results in "Couldn't find project.clj, which is needed for test". I don't know why the question was closed with mentioning "not meeting the stackoverflow guidelines" as it is a question on programming that is not fully answered up to now. Unfortunately I cannot reopen the question.

Comment: Ok, found a goot explanation under https://dev.to/adasomg/10-life-changing-minutes-with-clojure-windows-3ofl

Comment: *"I've never seen a programming language as difficult to install as Clojure."* Agreed (but then you haven't tried to install Scala 3!). It was Google that landed me here, while looking for simple ways to install Clojure on Windows; did you find an answer to your problem that does not require Leiningen?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Windoze much recently, but I have [a nice template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) that has everything you need to get started.

Clone the template project in git, then verify you have java and lein installed:

```
~/expr/demo > java --version
java 14 2020-03-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)

~/expr/demo > lein --version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Leiningen 2.9.1 on Java 14 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

Assuming that works, you should be able to run the unit tests:

```
> lein clean 
> lein test

lein test _bootstrap

-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 14
-------------------------------

lein test tst.demo.core

Ran 3 tests containing 8 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

You can edit the source code with any editor or IDE you like.  Note that the code is split into the `src` and `test` trees.  The project even includes a sample of how to include Java source code if you need it (or you can delete that part).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use Leiningen, start with Leiningen; no need to install Clojure beyond what Leiningen installs for you.  Then, look for a plugin for VS Code or whatever.

Comment: Well I found a script in www that downloaded and installed for me a working Leiningen. But if I want to get an executable that runs as jar I finally need to run clj. For vs code I installed calva, but without the proper directory and file structure the (println "Hello World") is not executed.